# View of Action Bar set with `setContentView()` not apply on items added through `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my application I am setting the custom view for Action bar using `setCustomView` method. This view contains blue background color and title of activity in center.

Here is my xml file for setting custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@color/darkblue" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code to add it in Activity Action Bar:

```
actionBar=getActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

Now I add the menu item (search) to this customized action bar using following code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater=getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }
```

But now the background of this added menu(search) item is not blue, it is default black color of Action bar.

Here is my menu `xml` file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"/>
   </menu>
```

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: Anybody please answer my question..

Comment: If you need any other info then please asked me

Comment: Is anybody has used setcontentview yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your code is working...

[image]

Please compare:

```
package com.example.testaction;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.test_action);
        actionBar
                .setDisplayOptions(com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

**EDITED**

**Insted Of Above Code use Custome Theam Like below then your problem is solved:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colour_blue</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/colour_blue</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

in Class:

```
package com.example.testaction;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_Light);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*
         * actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
         * actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.test_action); actionBar
         * .setDisplayOptions
         * (com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
         */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

add this style in Android Manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme" >
```

its look like:

[image]

for more detail look in to this [artical](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: yes it's working but here I am also adding an search item on Action Bar. This item added but its background is not blue but default black color. How do I manage this

Comment: I have added the menu.xml file

Comment: If you need any more information then asked me. I am stuck on this from a while

Comment: check my edited ans its is your best solution. you can also change style as per your req. if you think about to change manu item background then you have to do your awn way.. or may be using some customization. that whay i ll saggest you to do style.